# Java add 1D vector to 2D vector

Tags: java, vector, type-2-dimension

I got a problem when I tried to add 1D vector to 2D vector.

I wrote specific codes as following

```
Vector<Vector<String>> multiVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
Vector<String> singleVector = new Vector<String>();

singleVector.add("a,a,a");                      
System.out.println(singleVector);               // [a,a,a]
multiVector.add(singleVector);                  
System.out.println(multiVector);                // [[a,a,a]]
singleVector.clear();                         
singleVector.add("b,b,b");                      
System.out.println(singleVector);               // [b,b,b]
multiVector.add(singleVector);                  
System.out.println(multiVector);                // [[b,b,b], [b,b,b]]
```

At the last line, I expected that "[[a,a,a], [b,b,b]]" but the result was "[[b,b,b], [b,b,b]]"

What is wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that you shouldn't use Vector class at all. It's a legacy class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're adding the `singleVector` object to `multiVector`, you're *not* making a copy of it. So when you clear the `singleVector` and change it to "b,b,b" you're also "changing" the (same) object that you added to `multiVector`.

If you want to change `singleVector` without modifying `multiVector` you should `singleVector = new Vector<>()` instead of `clear()`'ing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the same Vector, already added to multiVector, and redefined its value. If you like to add a new one you have to write:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> multiVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
Vector<String> singleVector = new Vector<String>();
singleVector.add("a,a,a");                      
System.out.println(singleVector);               // [a,a,a]
multiVector.add(singleVector);                  
System.out.println(multiVector);                // [[a,a,a]]
singleVector = new Vector<String>();                        
singleVector.add("b,b,b");                      
System.out.println(singleVector);               // [b,b,b]
multiVector.add(singleVector);                  
System.out.println(multiVector);                // [[a,a,a], [b,b,b]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the object itself, not the value, so when you change the value of `singleVector` o you clear it, you are doing it on the `multivector` added one!

You must do as it follows:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> multiVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
Vector<String> singleVector1 = new Vector<String>();
Vector<String> singleVector2 = new Vector<String>();

singleVector1.add("a,a,a");                      
System.out.println(singleVector1);               // [a,a,a]
multiVector.add(singleVector1);                  
System.out.println(multiVector);                // [[a,a,a]]
singleVector2.add("b,b,b");                      
System.out.println(singleVector2);               // [b,b,b]
multiVector.add(singleVector2);                  
System.out.println(multiVector);                // [[a,a,a], [b,b,b]]
```